# Openshift mongodb url

Tags: php, mongodb, connection, openshift

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException'

with message

> 'Failed to connect to: :0: Connection refused'

When I use the url given by openshift:

```
$m =new MongoClient("mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/");
```

I have tried various including

```
$m =new MongoClient("mongodb://admin:<password here >@$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/");
```

I can connect through rockmongo so MongoDB is running ok

Answer (score 1):

```
"mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/" is a string.
```

You can access the environment variable using $_ENV array.

```
$dburl = $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL'];

$m = new MongoClient($dburl);
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply, the $_ENV'OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL'] is not set, where is this set please?

Comment: This environment variable is set when you add mongodb cartridge. You can ssh to that machine and type 'export' to list all the available environment variables.

Comment: What if I don't have access to environment variables, e.g. if I want to talk to mongodb on openshift from php script hosted on external website ?